# minipage goes beyond right margin

Tags: margins, minipage

```
\begin{minipage}[c][3cm]{0.075\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{Capture}
\end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[c][3cm]{0.85\textwidth}
   \centering{\bfseries{\scriptsize blah blah blah blah} \vfill
{\large blah blah blah blah}}\vfill
(\small blah blah blah blah blah blah)\\
blah blah blah
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[c][3cm]{0.075\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Capture1}
  \end{minipage}
```

Comment: Yes, of course it will. Leave a blank line between the `minipage`s (or an explicit `\par`), otherwise they're stacked one next to the other on the same line, causing your problem.

Comment: @Werner Their widths add up to `\textwidth`, so the problem could be a missing `\noindent` before the first one. (Unless of course the `Capture1` graphic is wider than `0.075\textwidth`.) 

shruthi: It is always best if you make *complete* examples, starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`, so that we can copy and compile the code directly. When images are part of an example, you can either add the `demo` option to `graphicx`, or use the images from the `mwe` package, e.g. `\includegraphics{example-image}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: True. I misread `0.075` as `0.75`. My (rather speculative) guess is that  `Capture` is far wider than `0.075\textwidth`, as the OP uses `scale` rather than `width`.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to tell as you have not provided a proper example but the outer two minipage are not doing a lot, and probably you should use `width` rather than `scale` to ensure the final width. Also the row as a whole needs to be not indented, finally beware `{\large blah blah blah blah}` a size change command should always include `\par` or a blank line at the end, otherwise you will set large (or small) text on a *normal* baseline.

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.075\textwidth]{Capture}%
\begin{minipage}[c][3cm]{0.85\textwidth}
   \centering
 {\bfseries{\scriptsize blah blah blah blah\par} \vfill
{\large blah blah blah blah\par}}\vfill
(\small blah blah blah blah blah blah\par)\\
blah blah blah
\end{minipage}%
\includegraphics[width=0.075\textwidth]{Capture1}
\end{center}
```